# How to add O(N) and O(M)?

Tags: java, time, time-complexity, big-o

Say I have two operations that are O(N), so I represent one as O(N) and the other as, say, O(M). If I added them together, what would it be? There's no telling which one is the greater of the two.

Also, is O(N) + O(M) the same as O(N + M)? If so, why?

Comment: There is no such thing as `O(N) + O(M)`.

Comment: Which one is greater does not matter.  What matters is whether one is asymptotically bounded by a function of the other, and if so, what the nature of that functional bound is.

Comment: Is the input to both the same?  If so, N and M are equal.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is `N`,`M`, then yes: `O(N) + O(M) = O(N+M)`.

Why is that?

**O(N) + O(M) is bounded by O(N+M):**

`O(N) + O(M)` is `a*N + b*M` operations [where `a`, `b` are constants].

`a*N + b*M <= (a+b)*N + (a+b)*M = (a+b)*(N+M) <= c*(N+M)` [where `c` = `a` + `b`].

`c` is constant so `c*(N+M)` is `O(N+M)`.

**O(N+M) is bounded by O(N) +O(M):**

`O(N+M) = e*(N+M) = e*N + e*M` [for some constant e],

which is `O(N) + O(M)`